# Disconnecting from Blynk app network using SIM7600 4G and switch sensor in a phone app

Tags: android, sensors, blynk

Can anybody  help me with I have a phone app by blynk with sim7600 4G and switch sensor.
when i place it, I call it to disconnect me from the network ( the app).
it is like an alarm app , i can send sms but can't place a call.

Want to send sms and call but unable to do so.